# ListViewItem MouseDoubleClick MVVM way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm converting my project to use MVVM Light.

So far everything worked fine until I got stuck with binding ListViewItem MouseDoubleClick to a command.

Now it looks like that:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsFromStash" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      ItemsSource="{Binding DropBox.DroppedItems}" 
      ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DropItemTemplate}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding DropBox.SelectedDropItem}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Control.MouseDoubleClick" 
                         Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

I'd like to make it look somewhat like that:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsFromStash" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DropBox.DroppedItems}" 
          ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DropItemTemplate}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DropBox.SelectedDropItem}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <Custom:EventToCommand Command=
                        "{Binding DropBox.RenameItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

But it says:

> Property 'Triggers' is not attachable to elements of type 'Style'

I tried moving the command to ListView.MouseDoubleClick, but than the SelectedItem is null sometimes.

How should do it?

Comment: if its important for you to recognize the item , you can create a behavior which there you add a handler to click event to the listview and there 
 e.OriginalSource should be the listviewitem

Comment: Do you know why they are null sometimes? can you repeat the behavior? Also, for future references, the next bit is rather useless in the question, since it adds nothing, and just make people read code they don't need: `Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

Comment: @Noctis Unfortunately I can't repeat it every time. It seems to be random.

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
 <ListView x:Name="lw" ItemsSource="{Binding DroppedItems}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.RenameItemCommand, ElementName=lw}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>

         <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <Label Content="{Binding Field}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Your command:

```
private ICommand renameItemCommand;
    public ICommand RenameItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (renameItemCommand == null)
            {
                renameItemCommand = new RelayCommand(
                                       param => RenameItem()
                                   );
            }
            return renameItemCommand;
        }
    }

private void RenameItem()
{

}
```

Comment: I tried fixed this problem
Please, see my answer, I changed it. I check, all work fine)))

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me on a listbox, it should be the same:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox_name_here" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding LastEntries}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedExercise, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    MinHeight="150" ToolTip="Double click to edit"
    >

  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding your_command_name_here}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listbox_name_here, 
                                         Path=SelectedItem}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</ListBox>
```

Do note that the command parameter is using the listbox (listview in your case) name to bind the target for the selected item.

Comment: with your code, if you select the item then double click anywhere in listView even on the column header, it will fire the event. ofcourse this's not what it meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to create a DataTemplate for the ListView items, and include your EventTrigger there. For example,

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsFromStash" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding DropBox.DroppedItems}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DropItemTemplate}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding DropBox.SelectedDropItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        <Custom:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DropBox.RenameItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <!-- Place your template controls here -->
            </Grid>                                        
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```